# provide assembly with full trust in sharepoint by custom policy level not working

Tags: security, sharepoint, assemblies, policy, cas

I'm building a couple of ucercontrols. These usercontrols will be hosted within the [return of the smartpart](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=10697). The problem i'm facing is that my assembly that goes with them, is not properly provided with sufficient rights.

To achive this you've (basically) got three options;
1. set the site to full trust level (do not want this obviously, aint working for me either. The assembly is not trusted)
2. place the assembly in the gac (tried that too, also not working).
3. security wise what I would like is to grant my assembly with a special set of rights.

This can be done by means of a custom trust file. This is what I came up with so far, but it is not working. Can someone point me in the right direction on this one?

added these two clauses at the security classes element;

```
<SecurityClass Name="AssemblyOne" Description="MyAssemblies.AssemblyOne, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=132bddbb4f2e45f2"/>
<SecurityClass Name="AssemblyTwo" Description="MyAssemblies.AssemblyTwo, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e5141be41498e913" />
```

added this clause in the named permission sets

```
        <PermissionSet
                class="NamedPermissionSet"
                version="1"
                Name="SPFULL"
                Unrestricted="true">
          <IPermission
                  class="AspNetHostingPermission"
                  version="1"
                  Level="Minimal"
                        />
          <IPermission
                  class="SecurityPermission"
                  version="1"
                  Flags="Execution"
                        />
          <IPermission class="WebPartPermission"
                  version="1"
                  Connections="True"
                        />
          <Assemblies>
            <Assembly Name="MyAssemblies.AssemblyOne" Version="1.0.0.0" PublicKeyBlob="002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010015fd63eb99fee087978556fcf698fae059d75307d1ee8e44486a349ea87843344440af9051d4434bac1d219b3a219d5f0ff50e8c0ed9eb7c07eab19d9ff0494ecaafc5ce1cb65d59ddd153b0f09790d6641af0325aaceb81c2e55c4610a1c18ae9f5a476de2282918a293726bce20aa932e06666b4e8b6885775b919a93a91a9" />
            <Assembly Name="MyAssemblies.AssemblyTwo" Version="1.2.0.0" PublicKeyBlob="00240000048000009400000006020000002400005253413100040000010001007da2bfd8e8ec53bd9caa8a5e3af2408cabd60b04c1df80bf8cbad447addaa8a7854818c77ea4f1ada3b73f33836b716999a5aac2475b22c676cedb3fe42cb2ebfba9dc20c04b1baab5a75ead6169b45d1dbef0bcbe82d5f862f954739ed100eaf41425eddd559aee883c055da038d0d8c2e998db799d6e1995ddea95a48eb0b4" />
          </Assemblies>
        </PermissionSet>
```

then I added this clause above the the existing 'default' code group;

```
<CodeGroup
        class="UnionCodeGroup"
        version="1"
        PermissionSetName="SPFULL"
        Name="My first Web Part"
        Description="This code group grants the my first web part full permissions.">
        <IMembershipCondition
          class="StrongNameMembershipCondition"
          version="1"              PublicKeyBlob="002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010015fd63eb99fee087978556fcf698fae059d75307d1ee8e44486a349ea87843344440af9051d4434bac1d219b3a219d5f0ff50e8c0ed9eb7c07eab19d9ff0494ecaafc5ce1cb65d59ddd153b0f09790d6641af0325aaceb81c2e55c4610a1c18ae9f5a476de2282918a293726bce20aa932e06666b4e8b6885775b919a93a91a9" />
        <IMembershcipCondition
          Class="StrongNameMembershipCondition"
          version="1"
          PublicKeyBlob="00240000048000009400000006020000002400005253413100040000010001007da2bfd8e8ec53bd9caa8a5e3af2408cabd60b04c1df80bf8cbad447addaa8a7854818c77ea4f1ada3b73f33836b716999a5aac2475b22c676cedb3fe42cb2ebfba9dc20c04b1baab5a75ead6169b45d1dbef0bcbe82d5f862f954739ed100eaf41425eddd559aee883c055da038d0d8c2e998db799d6e1995ddea95a48eb0b4"/>
      </CodeGroup>
```

Can anyone point out to me how to get this right?

Comment: What's the error that you get placing your assembly into the GAC? Was the SmartPart assembly also GAC'd at the time?

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see how putting both dll in the GAC or changing the web.config setting to FullTrust doesn't work. You cant give it more permissions than that. Are you sure the problem you are experiencing is security related? In case your putting just one of the dlls in the GAC, do you have the [assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]-attribute?

Just a side note:
You should put your permission set in the WSP:s manifest.xml instead, that will make sure SharePoint sets the right permisson for the dll on all frontweb when the feature is deployed. It will make administration easier.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543901.aspx

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know.